# merge branch into trunk because of tree conflicts?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I'm really new to SVN and seem to be missing something here...

I have a SVN checkout of my trunk which is a running website. I created a branch to which I made numerous changes. I would now like to merge those changes into the trunk.

So I:

- Right click the trunk checkout folder
- Select "Merge...", then "Reintegrate a branch..."
- The "From url" shows the location of the branch while "Working copy" shows the path of my trunk checkout
- When I click "Next" and then "Test merge" it shows lots of tree conflicts (all of which are files/changes I made in the branch)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: After 100500 same issues I understood: SVN can't merge. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You done nothing wrong (almost nothing), except exploring SVN-merge limitation before refactoring of code. "Tree conflict" appear on merge if same file (for both sides) was renamed (moved) on one side and edited on another. Is it your case? See my [trunk](http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/) and [branch](http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/branches/i18n/), it's my example of tree confict in action.

In order to get merge done, you can merge **files** before merge pathes, by hand - i.e merge all sources of tree-conflicts (trunk-file && branch-file)

Answer (score 2):

I think the following should work, and would be the best way:

1. Merge **from** trunk to your branch. (You always want trunk to be buildable).
2. Resolve the conflicts on your branch.
3. Merge your branch back to trunk.

---

If all your changes are checked in to your branch:

1. Switch to trunk.
2. Merge the changes from your branch to trunk.
3. Resolve the conflicts on your working copy.
4. Check it all back into trunk.

Comment: Merging from trunk to branch 'worked' but nothing was changed. After that I tried merging from branch to trunk but still the tree conflicts were there...

Comment: I've added another possible solution.